# Firefox CSS Floating Issue

Tags: html, css

as you can see, everything is okay in Chrome but i have floating problem in Firefox. please check website and give advise for solution.. thank you.

Comment: Show your code that is causing the issue, and describe what you have tried to do to solve the problem. Lastly, don't over tag -- php, and javascript are relevant to your problem.

Comment: i dont know. what is causing the issue. it is my question. and i was give tag "php and javascript" because it can be triggered from javascript. and php developers also know html and css.

Comment: It is a html/css issue only. But you should also include what you have already tried. Search SO for "how to ask a question" for more tips.

Comment: yes. it is my mistake. i will try this for next question. thank you

Comment: This question is the poster boy for why code is required to be posted here, and not a third-party site, as the code linked to has changed and is no longer relevant to the question leaving no future visitor any way of solving a similar issue. @MertGönül you did a disservice to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:left` and replace `position: absolute` by `position: relative` on `.cd-dropdown-wrapper` class.

Comment: it is works! but now;  http://i.hizliresim.com/P07arQ.png . as you can see sub menu floating.

Comment: Yes, because you have to set `position` as `absolute` or `relative` on parent if you want their children be positioned with absolute coordinates. I edited my answer, is it ok for you ?